# Using NSKeyedArchiver to store custom data model

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm working on a rss reader. It is just a tableview and each cell shows a custom data model RSSEntry. And I have a NSMutableArray allEntries which contains all RSSEntry I got from the server. This is what RSSEntry looks like:

```
    @interface RSSEntry : NSObject <NSCoding> {
        NSString *_blogTitle;
        NSString *_articleTitle;
        NSString *_articleUrl;
        NSDate *_articleDate;
    }
```

I want to restore data from local archive so when I quit and open this app again, the tableview is populated with data when last refresh.

I've read example in 'Beginning iOS5 Programming', but it only store and restore only one data model. So I don't know how to store this mutable array full of my custom data model and restore it.

I use following code to store and restore data:

```
// STORE
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init]; 
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
[archiver encodeObject:entry forKey:kDataKey];
[archiver finishEncoding];

// RESTORE
NSData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[self dataFilePath:kFilename]];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
RSSEntry *entries = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:kDataKey];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
```

I can only store and restore one data model in this way.

Who can give me a hand. I'm new to iOS programming, maybe it's a little dull .sorry.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Place all the entries you want to store into an `NSArray` and use this code:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:entries];
```

Where `entries` is your array of entries. Nice and easy, just one line of code.

To unarchive, just use

```
NSArray *entries = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

`NSKeyedArchiver` is able to archive any data structure, even a very complex one, of Objective-C objects **that implement the `NSCoding` protocol**, including nested `NSArray`s, `NSDictionary`s, and custom objects, to a file. `NSKeyedUnarchiver` does the reverse, taking any data produced by `NSKeyedArchiver` and reestablishing the original object graph that was archived. Technically, they could just be a single class, but Apple decided to separate them by functionality because this is more grammatically correct or something :)

I assume you are able to write the resulting `NSData` object to a file, and read it back again.

Comment: Don't know why but this answer works when all the others which seem identical don't - thanks

Answer (score 6):

You could store an NSDictionary as following

```
NSDictionary *Your_NSDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Obj1", @"Key1",
                               @"Obj2", @"Key2", nil];
//store dictionary
NSMutableData *yourData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:yourData];
[archiver encodeObject:Your_NSDictionary forKey: @"key"];
archiver finishEncoding];
[yourData writeToFile:@"FilePath" atomically:YES];
[yourData release];
[archiver release];


//Load dictionary

NSData *yourData = [[NSMutableData alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"FilePath"];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:yourData];
Your_NSDictionary = [unarchiver decodeObjectForKey: @"key"];
[unarchiver finishDecoding];
[unarchiver release];
[yourData release];
```

Answer (score 2):

For iOS 12:

for `archivedDataWithRootObject`:

```
NSData *myDicData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:AllDataDic 
                                     requiringSecureCoding:YES error:nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myDicData forKey:@"Yourkey"];
```

for `unarchivedObjectOfClass`:

```
NSData *tempData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Yourkey"];
NSDictionary *myDicProfile = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:[NSDictionary class] 
                                                fromData:tempData error:nil];
```