# Archive/Unarchive Parent-Child objects with a key

Tags: objective-c, nskeyedarchiver

I have a class `A` and a subclass `B`:

```
@interface A:NSObject<NSCoding>
String a;
String b;
@end
@interface B: A<NSCoding>
int c;
// `a` and `b` attributes are inherited
@end;
```

I want to archive some objects of `A` and some of `B` using attribute `a` as `key`.
The `encoding` and `decoding` protocols in both class have been defined as:

```
@implementation A
...
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    //[super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    [encoder encodeObject:self forKey:a];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    // self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self=[super init]) {
        self = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:a];
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@implementation B
..
 - (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [super encodeWithCoder:encoder];
    [encoder encodeObject:self forKey:super.a];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    //self = [super initWithCoder:decoder];
    if (self) {
        self = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:super.a];
    }
    return self;
}
```

For some object list `dataArray = [A("One"), B("Two")]`, the archiving logic is

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:dataArray];
            NSError* error = nil;
            BOOL success = [data writeToFile: @"xyz.dat" options:0 error: &error];
            if (!success)
                NSLog( @"error = %@", [error description] );
```

Again reading from the archived data:

```
NSData *lD = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"xyz.dat"];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *arc = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:lD];
```

Now for the object with the attribute `a` as`"One"`
While trying to read the object back from archived data, i am getting `null`!

```
 NSLog(@"Value - %@",[arc decodeObjectForKey:@"One"]);
```

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41116832/when-archive-object-in-the-func-encodewith-acoder-nscoder-method-crashed-with/41116908#41116908

Answer (score 0):

Maybe,the problem was with encoding `self`.
I did the following changes:

```
@implementation A
...
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    if(self.a!=nil)
        [encoder encodeObject:self.a forKey:@"a"];
    if(self.b!=nil)
        [encoder encodeObject:self.b forKey:@"b"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self=[super init];
    if (self!=nil) {
        self.a= [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"a"];
        self.b= [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"b"]; 
    }
    return self;
}
@end

@implementation B
..
 - (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
     [super encodeWithCoder:encoder ];
     [encoder encodeObject:self.c forKey:@"c"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if ( (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder ]) )
    {
        self.c= [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"c"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

While encoding data:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary new]; 
[dict setObject:[[A alloc]init()] forKey:@"One"];//say
[dict setObject:[[B alloc]init()] forKey:@"Two"];//say

NSMutableData *yourData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:yourData];
for (NSString* key in dict) {
    id value = [dict objectForKey:key];
    [archiver encodeObject:value forKey: key];
}
[ archiver finishEncoding];
[yourData writeToFile:@"xyz.dat" atomically:YES];
[yourData release];
[archiver release];
```

And decoding:

```
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"xyz.dat"];
NSKeyedUnarchiver *keyArc= [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
NSLog(@"%@",[keyArc decodeObjectForKey:@"One"]);
NSLog(@"%@",[keyArc decodeObjectForKey:@"Two"]);
[keyArc finishDecoding];
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929284/2301570